# How to use PSPDFKit check use main thread code in background thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pspdfkit

My application is slowly frequently.This UI is chaos.I am impossible.I want use PSPDFKit check use main thread code in background thread.Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Happy to share and help!

We at [PSPDFKit](https://pspdfkit.com/) (An SDK to view and edit PDF documents) open source smaller parts of our SDK regularly and also share knowledge via our [blog](http://blog.pspdfkit.com/). You can find the main thread guard code here:

https://gist.github.com/steipete/5664345

I updated the gist to no longer require the `PSPDFAssert` macro. While this was explained in the comments, I see how this might be confusing if you just wanna be fast and copy the code without actually reading it :)

Comment: Thanks! I will read this code diligently.